# replace string within file and the filename

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string `test.cgi@action=<action-name>`

`<action-name>` can be any string

I would like to replace the above string with `<action-name>.html`

Can any one please let me know how I can proceed with this using a Perl script?

Comment: can you clarify what you would like to replace with .html ? the entire string or just .cgi ?

Comment: Given the data you've shown us, it's hard to see why: $string .= '.html'; isn't the answer :-)

Comment: Example...test.cgi@action=redirect...then the replaced string should be redirect.html

Comment: @Flimzy has the right answer then

Comment: How can i extend this to search and replace all the occurences of above string within a file?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$string =~ s/test\.cgi@action=(.*?)/$1.html/g;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try this out...if I extend this to all the files within a directory...how ca I implement this?...i.e replace all the files with names test.cgi@action=<action-name> as <action-name>.html??

Comment: So you're trying to rename a bunch of files? That's really not related to the question you asked originally, but you can do that with the `rename` command.  For example: `rename 's/^test\.cgi\@action=(.*)$/$1.html/' test.cgi*`

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for both issues. Btw, rename command seems not to work. I have a file test.cgi@action=manager and i'm expecting to get renamed to manager.html, but it doesn't work. Can you please let me know how to resolve this?. or how i can debug this.

Comment: I tried with following code, but this doesn't replace the string :   my $string = 'test.cgi@action=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx test.cgi@action=aaaaaayyyyyyyyyyytest.cgi@action=';

            $string =~ s/test\.cgi@action=(.*)/$1.html/;

            print $string;

Comment: What result are you expecting when your string contians multiples of these address-like substrings?

Comment: If the input is "test.cgi@action=xxx;intermediate arbitrary string...test.cgi@action=yyy;another arbitrary string...test.cgi@action=zzz;". The output should be "xxx.html;intermediate arbitrary string...yyy.html;another arbitrary string...zzz.html;". If you observe, string to be replaced i.e "test.cgi@action=<action-name>" is always terminated with a ";". Let me know if you are not clear with my description

Comment: I tried with the following: my $string = 'test.cgi@action=xxx; test.cgi@action=yyy;test.cgi@action='; $string =~ s/test\.cgi@action=(.*)/$1.html/g; print $string; (added /g in the end). But the output is the content within string i.e test.cgi@action=xxx; test.cgi@action=yyy;test.cgi@action=. I'm expecting to be "xxx.html; yyy.html"